# How to add a .png inside a canvas?

Tags: android, canvas

I have a game where a ball is bounced.. I would like to replace the drawen ball with a soccer-ball in a png format.

I've tried lot of things but nothing worked.

Here is my code for drawing the ball :

```
    public ball() {
    position = new Vector(0.0f, 0.0f);
    paused_velocity = velocity = new Vector(0.0f, 0.0f);
    paused_acceleration = acceleration = new Vector(0.0f, gravity);

    radius = 0.0f;
    delta = 0;

    ball_paint = PaintList.getRandPaint();

    start_time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.drawCircle(position.X(), position.Y(), radius, ball_paint);
}
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you png is present a ball.png in your drawable directory..

```
public Bitmap getBallBitmap()
{
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.ball);
}

@Override
protected void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    //ideally you should cache the value returned by getBallBitmap()
    canvas.drawBitmap(getBallBitmap(),position.X(), position.Y(), null);
}
```

Note that you should use onDraw() method instead of draw() method as much as possible.